# JSF 2.2 @ViewScoped (Mojarra) Weld 2.2.3 @Produces map for SelectItems throws java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, weld, view-scope

I have two producer based methods that produce maps used in a column of a h:dataTable. This is the simple page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<f:view contentType="text/html">
    <h:body>
        <h:form id="mainForm">
            <h:dataTable value="#{adminManager.expertisesubs}" 
                                var="_expertisesub">
                <h:column>
                    <h:outputText value="#{testMapTwo[_expertisesub.tempValue]}" />
                    <br />
                    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{_expertisesub.tempValue}">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{testMapOne}" />
                    </h:selectOneMenu>      
                </h:column>
            </h:dataTable>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</f:view>
</html>
```

The producer looks like this:

```
public class ExpertisemainProducerHelper implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -8387208055146539725L;


@Produces
@ViewScoped
@Named("testMapOne")
public Map<String, Integer> produceTestMapOne() {
    Map<String, Integer> theMap = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();

    theMap.put("FOUR", 4);
    theMap.put("FIVE", 5);
    theMap.put("SIX", 6);

    return theMap;
}


@Produces
@ViewScoped
@Named("testMapTwo")
public Map<Integer, String> produceTestMapTwo() {
    Map<Integer, String> theMap = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();

    theMap.put(4, "FOUR-2");
    theMap.put(5, "FIVE-2");
    theMap.put(6, "SIX-2");

    return theMap;
}
}
```

The dataTable iterates over the list expertisesubs which is a list of object expertisesub. That object has the simple field private field Integer tempValue with the standard setter/getter methods.

That page produces the following exception:

```
SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/faces/layouts/admin.xhtml]
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
at java.lang.Integer.compareTo(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TreeMap.getEntry(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TreeMap.get(Unknown Source)
at javax.el.MapELResolver.getValue(MapELResolver.java:52)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183)
at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:174)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:205)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:355)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:164)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:312)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.TableRenderer.renderRow(TableRenderer.java:386)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.TableRenderer.encodeChildren(TableRenderer.java:163)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1857)
at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1857)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1860)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1860)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:461)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The exception only occurs if the page references both produced maps using @ViewScoped in the method declaration. If I change the scope to @SessionScoped or remove reference to one or the other map on the page, the page works (no exceptions).

The page is not the real solution but a torn down minimal page that can produce the same error.

My environment is:

JSF 2.2 (Mojarra)
CDI (Weld 2.2.3)
Tomcat 7
Java 7 (latest build...tried earlier too)

I've configured my environment to support JSF 2.2x @ViewScoped as follows:

Empty beans.xml

web.xml entries:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener</listener-class>
</listener>
<resource-env-ref>
    <resource-env-ref-name>BeanManager</resource-env-ref-name>
    <resource-env-ref-type>javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager</resource-env-ref-type>
</resource-env-ref>
```

context.xml in META-INF:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
<Manager pathname="" />

<Resource name="BeanManager" 
    auth="Container"
    type="javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager"
    factory="org.jboss.weld.resources.ManagerObjectFactory" />
</Context>
```

**Note**: This all worked perfectly in Jsf 2. Weld 1.x. Custom @ViewScoped.

**Update**: I thought this might have been an issue with wiring up CDI to Tomcat 7 so I tried this in GlassFish 4 (I removed the context.xml, web.xml listener/resource, weld-servlet, and jsf lib so it all is dependent on the default GlassFish implementation). Same problem with same stack occurs in  GlassFish.

**Update July 2015**: 
Due to the recent activity on the post, I'm adding information about how I "worked around" the problem.

Basically, I removed direct reference to the producers from the page. Instead, I injected (CDI) the maps directly into the bean behind the page. I added some @PostConstruct code to iterate over the map and build SelectItem objects and place those into appropriate lists. I then referenced those fields (lists of SelectItem) on the page. Not nice, defeats the purpose of the producer, but in the end I had to get this moving forward and did not have time to download sources (CDI issue? JSF issue? Weld specific issue?), add debug, compile, and test. Thanks for the recent attention.

Comment: So the selectOneMenu works if you remove the outputText?

Comment: The whole things works if I change the producers to SessionScoped. If I leave them ViewScoped and remove outputText the selectOneMenu works or if I remove the selectOneMenu the outputText works. But with both on the page, it throws the listed exception.

Comment: Using `<h:selectOneMenu converter="javax.faces.Integer">` should solve the particular problem, but then I can't explain why it works fine when switching to session scope.

Answer (score 0):

Change your select item to this:

```
<f:selectItems value="#{testMapOne.entrySet()}" var="entry"  itemValue="#{entry.value}" itemLabel="#{entry.value}" />
```

And it should work.

Comment: While this can qualify as an answer if improved, it does not fit the criteria for a quality answer in its current state. Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Please read the question in full. It worked perfectly under JSF 2.0, Weld 1.x (where CDI also only works with javax.faces.view.ViewScoped of course).

Comment: Sorry for my bad answer earlier @DanBeaulieu, I really was going to ask in a comment, but I don't have enough reputation (and I think this anwser is not going to help with that...lol).

Comment: Jokes aside, @Gary have you tried to define in <f:selectItems> the atributtes "itemValue" and "itemLabel" to specifically tell what is what to JSF?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Luke I know that now...and my reputation is low...that's why I put on the answer, I was trying to help

Comment: Hi @FelipeMoraes - this post has automatically appeared in one of the review queues and my comment is auto-posted as we work through the queue. It may get deleted by the system too if enough users review it in the same way that I have done. You can read more here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work

Comment: I've changed my answer to a real answer now. Hope this ends the mess I started =)

Comment: A good answer also has an explanation why this change would help. Please add that to.

Comment: @Felipe. Thanks but I had already tried that. Anything I do that includes directly referencing the two view scoped producers in the page results in the same error. Also, I don't think you meant to say this: itemValue="#{entry.value}" itemLabel="#{entry.value}" (just a side note). I've added another edit with my work around, but I am not adding it as an answer because it did not answer my original questions/problem. It was only a work around.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem today, which took quite a while to debug. In my case I have a bean with several `@Produces @Named("someName") @ViewScoped` producers which all return ArrayLists. After debugging for hours I finally found the culprit. jsf-impl contains a `ViewScopeContextManager.java` with the following method:

```
/**
 * Get the name of the bean for the given object.
 *
 * @param instance the object.
 * @return the name.
 */
private String getName(Object instance) {
    String name = instance.getClass().getSimpleName().substring(0, 1).toLowerCase()
            + instance.getClass().getSimpleName().substring(1);

    Named named = instance.getClass().getAnnotation(Named.class);
    if (named != null && named.value() != null && !named.value().trim().equals("")) {
        name = named.value();
    }
    return name;
}
```

This gets called whenever `instance` is put into the ViewScope to find out it's name. In my case, this returns 'arrayList', since it only looks for the `@Named`-annotation on the class (ArrayList), where there is no such annotation, obviously.
The latest version of JSF 2.2 still contains this code, I will now look if 2.3 fixes it, and if not, maybe work on a fix.

Edit: Code is still in latest 2.3, I [reported the bug](https://github.com/javaserverfaces/mojarra/issues/4366).